# Android app to perminantly monitor a database and alert on change

Tags: android, background-process

I am looking to create an app that monitors an online sql database and alerts the user if records change. In case you're interested, the database is being updated by a computer as to the state of some sensors the computer is monitoring. I have already got the database and monitoring computer working perfectly and have made an app to see the data in a list view. What I want is an app that opens on start up and runs in the background constantly and when changes occur can trigger an alarm and a toast telling me what's going on. I suppose it's similar to all the push notifications your phone gets from facebook and the like but I intend the app to be actively querying the database.

Anyone able to help or point me in the right direction? I've looked around but can't seem to find the info. I'm sure it's there, I must just not be using the right terms.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest you to explore google cloud notifications to notify app via computer you are using to monitor data. It will not be a good solution to query database all time from an app.

Answer (score 0):

So basically here is the systems approach to what you're trying to do. You're going to want to establish some sort of websocket on your backend and some sort of NoSQL like Redis to help manage the pub/sub part to your Android App in order to stream live updates from your web/database server. Then when you go to update the record in your database you also send information over the websocket to your Android App.

That's the gist of how that type of thing works.